# Как проверить, имеется ли символы в конкретном элементе строки?

Tags: c#, wpf, строки

Имеется строка кода, которая проверяет строку на наличие заданных символов.
Как сделать так, чтоб проверить конкретный элемент строки на данные символы?

```
TextLabel.Text.IndexOfAny("÷×+-%".ToCharArray())
```

Comment: _конкретный элемент строки_ - расшифруйте, что это значит

Comment: К примеру, взять 0-й элемент

Comment: Или взять 2-й элемент строки

Comment: Что такое элемент? Символ чтоли? `"÷×+-%".Contains(TextLabel.Text[i])`

Comment: Да. К примеру: строка: "5-4332". Нужно взять 2 элемент (1 индекс) строки

Comment: Ага, как понимаю, строка кода будет выглядеть так: TextLabel.Text.IndexOfAny("÷×+-%".Contains(TextLabel.Text[0])); ?

Comment: Серьезно? Нет `if ("÷×+-%".Contains(TextLabel.Text[0])) { ... }`. Вы бы сначала проверили, а потом спрашивали.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)